# Reading and storing data from a TCP buffer in C

Tags: c, tcp

I am reading some HTTP POST data from an HTTP wrapped TCP socket. My apparatus works but there is a strange syndrome. Basically I know what the content length is (via HTTP header `Content-length`) but I more often than not seem to build up a buffer that is 2-3 bytes longer than expected. I know that I am not setting my buffer size on initialization but when I do I get a lot of compile errors. The following code almost works but often produces more data in the buffer than there should be.

```
long bytesRead;
unsigned long bytesRemaining;
sbyte *pBuffer;
sbyte *pTmpBuffer;

pBuffer = malloc(contentLength);
memset(pBuffer, 0, contentLength);

pTmpBuffer = pBuffer;
bytesRemaining = contentLength;
while(bytesRemaining > 0){
   if(maxBuffSize < bytesRemaining){
      chunkSize = maxBuffSize;
   }
   else {
      chunkSize = bytesRemaining;
   }

   bytesRead = tcpBlockReader(pHttpData, pTempBuff, chunkSize);
   bytesRemaining -= bytesRead;
   pTempBuff += bytesRead;
}

printf("Data is %s\n", pBuffer);
printf("Length is %d\n", strlen(pBuffer));
```

Now *sometimes* it will be perfect, ie

`Data is expected+data`

`Length is 13`

And sometimes it will be

`Data is expected+data+(weird characters)`

`Length is 15`

So the problem here I think is I don't set a size for the buffer (ie `pBuffer[contentLength]`). When I do this though I get errors of `incompatible types` and what not. I am not a well versed C programmer (usually stick to chars and ints). What can I do to ensure that the buffer is not full of extra garbage at the end?

Comment: Did You try to insert '\0' at the end of the string?

Comment: Try using calloc instead of malloc to zero out the memory before using it.

Comment: `calloc` is `malloc` + `memset` which I'm just doing manually already. The issue is that the buffer is somehow bigger than the content length

Comment: Did you remember to skip the \r\n sequence after the header fields?

Comment: @Surcle I think that did it..

Comment: Is `contentLength` the length you get given...in which case you need to add 1 to it for the NUL at the end when used with `malloc` etc...

Comment: Yes that was it @ChrisTurner

Answer (score -1):

I was missing the elusive NULL terminator.

`pBuffer = malloc(contentLength + 1)`

...

`pBuffer[contentLength] = '\0'`;